# Module Not Found After NPM and Node Update

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a React application that was working fine.  While trying to fix another problem I did a version update of NPM, TSC (Typescript) and Node.  I was able to fix the issue I was facing but webpack now fails to comppile.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstalling the module where I  get the error and then do a npm run for my web project but it again fails to compile.

```
ERROR in ./app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'grommet/utils/Rest' in 'C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\app'
resolve 'grommet/utils/Rest' in 'C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\package.json (relative path: ./app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\package.json (relative path: ./app)
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/grommet/utils/Rest)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Users\jgora\OneDrive\Documents\BloomSky\PatientTab\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Users\jgora\node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\jgora\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\jgora\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest.js doesn't exist
       .json
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\jgora\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest.json doesn't exist
        as directory
          C:\Users\jgora\node_modules\grommet\utils\Rest doesn't exist
```

Comment: try to update your webpack also that is compatible with updated npm version

Comment: tried that as well and did not work.  I did install npm-check which pointed out that i was missing dependencies and by adding the dependencies in my package.json files, npm-check now says i'm good to go.  However when i run my app I still get the Module Not found error.

Comment: Vikram thanks for the help updating webpack in combination with changing the resolve statemeent in my webpack.config did the trick.  Also using the tool npm-check and the webpack line...webpack --display-error-details really helps as well.  May be known to others but it was new to me.

Comment: glad to help:).and yes i also faced similar issues,so had an idea